# How to produce an error message for each argument?

Tags: pattern-matching, warning-messages, optional-arguments

I want to print a helpful message for every wrong input. How do you compactly implement a function with custom pattern constraints, default values and **error messages for each argument separately**? For example, argument x should be an integer, argument y should be a list containing 7 values, argument z ...

For instance, the following simple function works fine with pattern constraints and default values, but does not output any helpful message in case of wrong input.

```
f1[
   x_Integer,
   y : (_?(# >= 3 &)) : 3,
   z : (_?(Length@# == 2 &)) : {"a", "b"}
   ] := {x, y, z};
f1[2.]
f1[2]
f1[2, 1]
f1[2, 4]
f1[2, 4, {1, 2, 3}]
f1[2, 4, {1, 2}]
```

> f1[2.]

> {2, 3, {"a", "b"}}

> f1[2, 1]

> {2, 4, {"a", "b"}}

> f1[2, 4, {1, 2, 3}]

> {2, 4, {1, 2}}

The following attempt of mine to produce helpful messages is partly ok, but highly cumbersome and does not work well when `y` is wrong, see also the `Trace[f[2, 1]]` screenshot at the end.

```
f2::x = "Input x must be an integer.";
f2::y = "Input y must be greater than or equal to 3.";
f2::z = "Input z must have a length of 2.";
f2[
    x_,
    y_: 3,
    z_: {"a", "b"}
    ] /; If[
    IntegerQ[x],
    If[
     y >= 3,
     If[
      Length@z == 2,
      True,
      Message[f2::z];
      False
      ],
     Message[f2::y];
     False
     ],
    Message[f2::x];
    False
    ] := {x, y, z};
f2[2.]
f2[2]
f2[2, 1]
f2[2, 4]
f2[2, 4, {1, 2, 3}]
f1[2, 4, {1, 2}]
```

Output

> f2::x: Input x must be an integer.

> f2[2.]

> {2, 3, {"a", "b"}}

> f2::y: Input y must be greater than or equal to 3.

> f2::z: Input z must have a length of 2.

> f2[2, 1]

> {2, 4, {"a", "b"}}

> f2::z: Input z must have a length of 2.

> f2[2, 4, {1, 2, 3}]

> {2, 4, {1, 2}}

[image: Trace]

Comment: I would have a definition `f[x : patt1, y : patt2, z : patt3] :=` which matched the intended patterns and did no error handling, then a definition `f[args___] :=` which parsed the sequence `args` and told you which were wrong. (The more specific definition should be applied first by default.)

Comment: Could you demonstrate that? I do not know how to parse a sequence of arguments.